# How to use saml2aws similar functionality on Nodejs app

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, saml, adfs2.0

I am looking for suggestions on how to authenticate NodeJS server my AWS account using ADFS with Username and password followed by MFA Authentication to get a temporary access key and secret key for further actions.

For reference, I am trying to achieve what saml2aws do on the command-line interface. Here instead of a command-line interface, I would like to do it on my NodeJS server.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

So far I have the below code with me, It does half job for me like it enters ADFS creds and submits the request, and then triggers a notification to approve on my Microsoft authenticator app. But my code doesn't wait for that authenticator response. It just gets the body of the webpage where it waits for the authenticator to approve. I need some way to make it wait for the authenticator response, which will give me a SAML assertion response after ADFS credit submission.

````
require("dotenv").config();
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const sts = new AWS.STS();
const request = require("request").defaults({ jar: true });
const url = require("url");
const JSSoup = require("jssoup").default;
const os = require("os");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const ini = require("ini");

const HOME = os.homedir();
const CONFIG_FILE = path.join(HOME, ".aws", "credentials");

let IDP_URL = process.env.IDP_URL;
let IDP_USER = process.env.IDP_USER;
let IDP_PASS = process.env.IDP_PASS;
let AWS_PROFILE = process.env.AWS_PROFILE;
console.log(IDP_USER);
function base64encode(data) {
  return Buffer.from(data, "utf8").toString("base64");
}

function base64decode(data) {
  return Buffer.from(data, "base64").toString("utf8");
}

function httpGet(url) {
  const options = {
    url,
  };
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request.get(options, (error, response, body) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      } else {
        resolve({ response, body });
      }
    });
  });
}

function httpPost(url, form) {
  const options = {
    url,
    form,
    followAllRedirects: true,
  };
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request.post(options, (error, response, body) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      } else {
        resolve({ response, body });
      }
    });
  });
}

function getLoginData(body) {
  const soup = new JSSoup(body);
  const forms = soup.findAll("form");
  const form = forms.find((form) => form.attrs.id === "loginForm");

  if (!form) {
    throw new Error("LOGIN_FORM_NOT_FOUND");
  }

  const action = url.resolve(IDP_URL, form.attrs.action);
  const inputs = {};

  for (const input of form.findAll("input")) {
    const name = input.attrs.name || "";
    const value = input.attrs.value || "";
    const namelc = name.toLowerCase();

    if (namelc.includes("user")) {
      inputs[name] = IDP_USER;
    } else if (namelc.includes("email")) {
      inputs[name] = IDP_USER;
    } else if (namelc.includes("pass")) {
      inputs[name] = IDP_PASS;
    } else {
      inputs[name] = value;
    }
  }

  return { action, inputs };
}

function getSAMLAssertion(body) {
  const soup = new JSSoup(body);
  const inputs = soup.findAll("input");
  const saml = inputs.find((input) => input.attrs.name === "SAMLResponse");

  if (!saml) {
    throw new Error("SAML_ASSERTION_NOT_FOUND");
  }

  return base64decode(saml.attrs.value);
}

function getSAMLRoles(saml) {
  const soup = new JSSoup(saml);
  const roles = soup
    .findAll("AttributeValue")
    .filter((value) => {
      return (
        value.parent &&
        value.parent.name === "Attribute" &&
        value.parent.attrs &&
        value.parent.attrs.Name ===
          "https://aws.amazon.com/SAML/Attributes/Role"
      );
    })
    .map((value) => {
      const [provider, role] = (value.text || "").split(",");
      return { provider, role };
    });

  if (!roles[0]) {
    throw new Error("SAML_ROLE_NOT_FOUND");
  }

  return roles;
}

async function getSTSToken(provider, role, assertion) {
  const params = {
    DurationSeconds: 3600,
    PrincipalArn: provider,
    RoleArn: role,
    SAMLAssertion: base64encode(assertion),
  };
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    sts.assumeRoleWithSAML(params, (error, data) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      } else {
        resolve(data);
      }
    });
  });
}

function saveSTSToken(filename, profile, sts) {
  const readFile = () => {
    try {
      return ini.decode(fs.readFileSync(filename, "utf-8"));
    } catch (e) {
      return {};
    }
  };

  const writeFile = (config) => {
    fs.writeFileSync(filename, ini.encode(config, { whitespace: true }));
  };

  const config = readFile();
  const section = config[profile] || {};
  const credentials = sts.Credentials || {};

  section.aws_access_key_id = credentials.AccessKeyId;
  section.aws_secret_access_key = credentials.SecretAccessKey;
  section.aws_session_token = credentials.SessionToken;

  config[profile] = section;
  writeFile(config);
}

function checkUsage() {
  if (!IDP_URL) {
    throw new Error("IDP_URL not set!");
  }
  if (!IDP_USER) {
    throw new Error("IDP_USER not set!");
  }
  if (!IDP_PASS) {
    throw new Error("IDP_PASS not set!");
  }
  if (!AWS_PROFILE) {
    throw new Error("AWS_PROFILE not set!");
  }
}

(async function main() {
  try {
    console.log(`aws-saml-session started.`);
    checkUsage();

    console.log(`Logging into SAML provider...`);
    const resp1 = await httpGet(IDP_URL);
    const data = getLoginData(resp1.body);
    // This is the place its not waiting and getting me body of the page 
    //where it needs to wait and get me SAML response
    ```const resp2 = await httpPost(data.action, data.inputs);
    const saml = getSAMLAssertion(resp2.body);```

    const roles = getSAMLRoles(saml);

    const { provider, role } = roles[0];

    console.log(`Assuming role: ${role}...`);
    const sts = await getSTSToken(provider, role, saml);

    console.log(`Saving credentials: ${AWS_PROFILE}...`);
    saveSTSToken(CONFIG_FILE, AWS_PROFILE, sts);

    console.log("Done.");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("ERROR:", e.message);
  }
})();
````

Comment: What have you already tried? In the end it is a series for requests, redirects and HTML parsing. Anything specific you have problems with?

Comment: @AleksanderWons I have edited my question with the work so far I did and the place where I am stuck. I really need this to get it done. Please help

Comment: This request is completed.

Comment: Can you please share @PrashantGupta, how did it work in the end?